Why does passing one type argument to a function break the type recognition for the rest of the parameters when using generics?
Passing the type argument of the first function parameter breaks the type recognition of the following parameters when using generics. See below:
const useOneArg = <T = any>(argT: T) => {
    return {
        argT,
    }
}

const oneArg = useOneArg(1);
oneArg.argT // hover over argT to show type = number

const useTwoArgs = <T = any, R = any>(argT: T, argR: R) => {
    return {
        argT,
        argR
    }
}

const twoArg = useTwoArgs(2, "two");
twoArg.argT // hover over argT to show type = number
twoArg.argR // hover over argR to show type = string

const twoArgAgain = useTwoArgs<number>(2, "two");
twoArgAgain.argT // hover over argT to show type = number
twoArgAgain.argR // hover over argR to show type = any

// Explicitly stating what the first arg seems to confuse the function about the second arguments type

Playground
Is this intended behavior or is this a bug?
My use case is a little different but leads to the same issue:
const twoTypesOneArg = <T = any, R = any>(argR: R) => {
    return {
        data: [] as T[],
        argR
    }
}

const objTest1 = twoTypesOneArg(2);
objTest1.data // hover over data to show type = any[]
objTest1.argR // hover over argR to show type = number

const objTest2 = twoTypesOneArg<number>(2);
objTest2.data // hover over argT to show type = number[]
objTest2.argR // hover over argR to show type = any

// Explicitly stating the first generic arg leads to the parameters type being lost

Playground
Is there a way to define the first type argument and still have the second type argument inferred parameters type?

Partial inference isn't supported, see e.g microsoft/TypeScript#26242

@jonrsharpe Thanks for the link. I assume there's no decent workaround for this then? The best I've come up with is to provide two params instead of one, with an explicit initialization of [] as []MyType for the first param so the second still gets inferred.

Workarounds involve currying or dummying, see this playground link
